# Get handles of all windows in a WPF process

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, interop

I know I can get the MainWindowHandle by enumerating Process.GetProcesses but I also want to  get handles of all WPF windows a WPF app may have. I need to do this in a completely separate process. How would I do this? Thanks

Comment: WPF child controls aren't windowed. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: As @DavidHeffernan said, the child controls aren't windows except if they are as special kind of host for a real WIN32 window. Explore your application with Spy++ and see that most windows are not HWNDs. Probably only the main window is a real HWND window.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since a WPF process has multiple thread you have to enumerate all threads to find the windows.

I used the below Win32 method to do this. You create a list and add to the list in the callback that is called on each iteration.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadWindowsCallBack lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

 Win32.EnumThreadWindows(processThread.Id, (hWnd, lParam) =>
                {
                    if (Win32.IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
                    {
                        Win32.RECT windowRect;
                        Win32.GetWindowRect(hWnd, out windowRect);

                        if (hWnd != _currentWindowHandle)
                        {
                            windowList.Add(new WindowInfo(hWnd, windowRect));
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }, IntPtr.Zero);
```